# What is a good program for mixed mode circuit simulation?

Tags: software-rec, simulation, schematic

I'm looking for a program that will perform schematic capture and mixed-mode (analog and digital) circuit simulation.  If it also did PCB layout and routing, that would be a bonus, but not necessary.   I currently use an old version of CircuitMaker/TraxMaker, but it's dated, and the simulation engine is a bit lacking.  Windows or Linux, doesn't really matter.

What is a good program for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure how active they are, but you may have better luck on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ... Just seen this - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/software-for-pcb-design and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-there-a-freeware-shareware-version-of-pspice

Comment: You're probably aware of *spice* and it's commercial variants, like *hspice*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) from Linear Technology for simulation.
[KiCad](http://kicad.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for PCB

Answer (score 1):

[Multisim](http://www.ni.com/multisim/) from National Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following two links.

[Electronics Lab](http://www.electronics-lab.com/)

[OrCAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OrCAD)

If you want to try for "PIC uC" micro controllers specially, you can get useful software from [MicroChip](http://www.microchip.com/), and also ask in [their wiki](http://www.microchip.com/wiki/).

I've some useful software but you will need more time & value to pay for these. So I don't share.

But "ORCAD" is not bad for normal users for schematic capture, mixed-mode (analog and digital) circuit simulation, PCB layout and routing.

Comment: If you have content on www.microchip.com/wiki/ that you would like to share, please make a post on the Forum site in the appropriate thread. Forums can be found here http://www.microchip.com/forums/Default.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Try [qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/):

> Qucs is an integrated circuit simulator which means you are able to
>   setup a circuit with a graphical user interface (GUI) and simulate the
>   large-signal, small-signal and noise behaviour of the circuit. After
>   that simulation has finished you can view the simulation results on a
>   presentation page or window.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/tools/designtools.htm) (SP?).  I remember they had a pretty good sweet a few years ago when I was in college.  Requires either verilog or VHDL knowledge though, it won't just let you diagram it.

Comment: Digital (specifically FPGAs) only, not analogue though.

Answer (score 0):

[KiCad](http://kicad.sourceforge.net/) is a free schematic capture, PCB layout, gerber generator, etc package. Pretty capable and works decently well. It doesn't have built-in simulation, but I'd suggest LTSpice for that.

Answer (score 0):

NGspice is a mixed-level/mixed-signal circuit simulator. Its code is based on three open source software packages: Spice3f5, Cider1b1 and Xspice @ http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Find a better link than SourceForge to download these packages. SourceForge is still bundling its own bits inside of its downloadable files. Even though the new management of the SourceForge website has publicly denied doing this, I have investigated this matter, and found that this wrong practice is still occurring.

Comment: @karel, it looks like sourceforge is their official hosting site.  No other choice for a link.  But at least now readers are forewarned.  :-)